# I have an error with otp component in vuetify in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem in `vuetify` when I want to use OTP input component.

My code is here :
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/otp-input/#finish-event

```
<div class="ma-auto position-relative" style="max-width: 300px">
          <v-otp-input
            v-model="otp"
            :disabled="loading"
            @finish="onFinish"
          ></v-otp-input>
          <v-overlay absolute :value="loading">
            <v-progress-circular
              indeterminate
              color="primary"
            ></v-progress-circular>
          </v-overlay>
        </div>
```

My error is :

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @bassxzero its done now in my post

Comment: You need to post the entire Register component.

Comment: @bassxzero its very long I use another component in it and I dont have erro but I have this error for OTP

Comment: @faezeh which version of vuetify you are using? you have tagged vuetify3, is it ok?

Comment: @dreamwalker no this version :  "vuetify": "^2.2.26",

Comment: @faezeh `v-otp-input` was firstly introduced in vuetify 2.6.0. You should update to 2.6.0 to use this component

Comment: @dreamwalker thanx a lot

Comment: @dreamwalker how can i improve it to 2.6.0.?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input       You could use this package as an alternative , make sure to use the css stying which they gave in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because of your vuetify version (**vuetify version  must be 2.6.0 or higher**)

**for updating vuetify**:

1.Run npm info vuetify to lookup for the list of versions that they have.

```
npm info vuetify
```

2.install the specific version that you want with the following
for example:

```
npm install --save vuetify@2.6.6
```